# Insert one row between groups based on criteria in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet of data that has four columns. I want the spreadsheet to add 3 rows after each group based on column D. Column D has the department for the transactions. All department transactions are listed in a row. So Excel just needs to find the change in department and enter three rows after that section.

I have tried this code I found here. It puts a row after every line it sees the department in.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IMPORT-WIP") 'better define by name: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")

    Dim LastRow_f As Long
    LastRow_f = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("A1:D" & LastRow_f).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="HR DEPARTMENT"

    Dim FilteredData As Range
    Set FilteredData = ws.Range("D2:D" & LastRow_f).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Dim iArea As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iArea = FilteredData.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1 'loop from last to first area
        For iRow = FilteredData.Areas(iArea).Rows.Count To 1 Step -1 'loop from last row to first row in each area
            With FilteredData.Areas(iArea).Rows(iRow) '<-- this represents the current row we are in the loop
                .Offset(RowOffset:=1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                .Offset(RowOffset:=1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
            End With
        Next iRow
    Next iArea

    'remove filters
    ws.Range("A1:D" & LastRow_f).AutoFilter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will insert 3 rows between groups of values (even unique values). The data does not need to be filtered. It will loop through `Column D`, test the cell above the current cell and, if not the same value, will insert 3 rows between them. You may have to sort the data first, depending on what you want.

```
Sub InsertRowsBetweenGroups()
Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change as needed

lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lr - 1 To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "D") <> Cells(i - 1, "D") Then
            Cells(i, "D").Resize(3).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: GMalc, you are an amazing person. This worked perfectly!

Do you have any advice for learning VBA? I come on here a lot to steal code for projects but it is haphazard and ugly at best. I'm about to start a Computer Science program but always am open to advice from professionals.

Comment: @Doupis There are a number of vba courses online you can preview to get the basics. I've found S.O. the best source for learning and understanding vba. Identifying the knowledgeable individuals who provide free help to others, and reading their comments and answers, helps me understand more advanced vba coding.  I like to review S.O. questions and when I find one interesting, I try to figure out how I can accomplish the task as simple as possible. The bottom line is, the more code you write will increase your vba skills and knowledge.